# Restore iphone 5 with broken wake/sleep button

Tags: iphone

I have forgotten my 4-digit iphone passcode and want to restore it but have a broken wake/sleep button and cannot find a way to do so online, any suggestions?

Comment: Did you forget your AppleID password? Or the 4-digit code to get into the actual device?

Comment: 4-digit code to the device

Answer (score 1):

Follow Apple Support's guide for what to do if you forgot the passcode on your phone: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204306

You shouldn't need the sleep/wake button for this. Once you get your iPhone unlocked with the help of that article, turn on "AssistiveTouch" in Settings->General->Accessability so you can sleep your phone again.

Comment: The Recovery Mode mentioned in that article for the link you provided requires the use of the power button. I don't believe this will work.

Comment: @TMHahn I don't believe that it requires the use of the power button. If you have a mac, you can just plug your iPhone into iTunes and hit "restore iPhone".